# eclipse error :This version of the rendering library is more recent than your version of ADT plug-in. Please update ADT plug-in

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

I updated the `ADT` to `23.0.7` but still get the said error. My project build target is `android5.1.1` and `target=android-22`, but when I open the xml file it shows:

> The rendering target (Android 6.0) is still loading...,

and then

> This version of the rendering library is more recent than...,

and there is no button to change the preview target in the preview interface. I do not want to uninstall `android 6.0 sdk`,so what should i do?

Answer (score 0):

You can change your android rendering version from your xml's graphical layout page.

At that screen you can see robot symbol with version. By clicking that you can solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

you can download Android SDK toolkit of AndroidStudio of your version or change API version